# Watir : How do we capture the subitems displayed by doing mouseover on a particular item

Tags: watir

I am trying to work with mouseover on a particular Item in my application by using the following command
{

ie.text_field(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Deal')]").fire_event('onmouseover')

}

On doing mouseover on a item, two subitems are displayed.

Is there any way to capture the sub items which are part of the Item by doing mouseover with which we can report that our test is pass or fail.

Please suggest.

Additional Information :

If we take example,On the StackOver flow page, If i do mouseover on my name, i get a window where i see activity, privileges, Logout and other stuff. This is really what i was looking for. Is there a way to capture the items displayed on the window on doing mouseover.

I also tried to capture the subitems with the following :
{

text=ie.text_field(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Deal')]").fire_event('onmouseover')

puts(text.inspect)

}

On doing this "text" value is displayed as 'nil'.

Comment: Please show us the HTML for that part of the page, and the code you are trying to make work.

Comment: You also need to be a bit more clear regarding what you mean when you say 'two subitems are displayed'..  displayed how? do you mean like a tooltip, or does something on the page actually change?  As examples, is it like what you see when you float the mouse over your reputation number at the top of the Stackoverflow page?  or when you put it over your name?  (both have things appearing, but both are done in different ways)

Comment: 5 days since requests for more info and not a peep.  6 questions asked, all now with at least one answer, and no answers accepted by the questioner.   I am rapidly reaching the conclusion that @ajazz doesn't really care about getting answers to their questions and that attempting to interact or help them is simply not worth the time and effort.

Comment: Hey Chuck, 

I was not aware of the fact that I need to accept the answer. Since I have realized that I need to do this, I will continue to accept the answer in future provided it works.

Apologies from my end.

Regards,
Ajazz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general tactic for such things is a combination of using IRB and the IE Developer tool, or Firebug.

using IRB, type out (or cut and paste) the watir statement to fire the onmouseover command to the proper element on the page.

Then have the developer tool rescan the DOM (there's a little refresh icon you can click)  The use the tool to point to an element to point to one of the items in the stuff exposed by the onmouseover.    Using the info from that, you can then figure out how to address those elements to get the text from the proper div, etc.

If I do that here to the info that opens up when I float the mouse over my name I can find out that it is a table of class "profile-recent-summary"  Furthermore I can then look at the way the table is made up and see for example that the 'today' reputation value is in the second cell on that row..  The row also has the text 'reputation' in it..  so

```
browser.table(:class, 'profile-recent-summary').row(:text, /reputation/).cell(:index, 2).flash
```

Should flash the cell I want  (index might be 1 if using firewatir or webdriver) I can then replace the .flash  with something else like .text if I want to get the text from that cell (which is actually inside a link that sits in the cell)..

Comment: Thanks chuck, I have used ".text" and was able to retrieve the sub items displayed on doing mouseover

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code, I would 'inspect' the element that you are trying to verify and when_present (text) assert that its true